# How to resolve PIL unidentified image error in flask app

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am taking a flask tutorial course at https://deeplizard.com, which seeks to predict cats and dogs. The code works well until the predict function is called. Here is a summary of the error message I get:

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [POST]

PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000023708CF4BE8>
```

Below are the backend and full error details. I would appreciate help with this error.
The backend code is from https://deeplizard.com/learn/video/XgzxH6G-ufA. Thank you.

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, img_to_array
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__) #instance of flask class

def get_model():
    global model
    model = load_model('VGG16_cats_and_dogs.h5')
    print(" * Model loaded!")
    

def preprocess_image(image, target_size):
    
    if image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")
    image = image.resize(target_size)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    return image

print(" * Loading Keras model...")
get_model()

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"]) 

def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    encoded = message['image']
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    processed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size=(224, 224))
    prediction = model.predict(processed_image).tolist()

    response = {
        'prediction': {
            'dog': prediction[0][0],
            'cat': prediction[0][1]
        }
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

The error details are below:

```
[2021-02-23 08:43:26,191] ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Akua\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Akua\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Akua\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Akua\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Akua\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Akua\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Akua\SDSMT G DRIVE\SDSMT Academics\COURSES\SUMMER 2019\Machine Learning - Discussions _ Coursera_files\Keras\Deep lizard\DogsAndCats\predict_app.py", line 67, in predict
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
  File "C:\Users\Akua\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2959, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000023708CF4BE8>
```

Comment: What are the first 20bytes in `io.BytesIO(decoded)` please? And please identify the lines of code that created that data. Thank you.

Comment: It can be the case that `message['image']` contains some extra symbols besides base64 data. Or on client side image was encoded to base64 incorrectly. Please print to us first 30-40 symbols of `message['image']`.

Comment: Also do you have a link to source code of your HTML on client side? That calls /predict and base64-encodes an image. Probably mistake is inside HTML/JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks, @Arty. Your comments made me take a second look at the HTML code. The code had been set to work with png files, and all along, I had been attempting to predict for jpg files, hence the error. After converting to png, the prediction works successfully. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. I appreciate your comment and time. It's now been resolved.